# Chinese 'jianpu' notation in MusicXML: Any example files, or notation tools?

Tags: notation, musicxml

I'm doing background research for a project to write a software tool that converts between Western music notation, and [Chinese numbered '*jianpu*' notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numbered_musical_notation), and [South Asian '*swara*' notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swara) systems.

The use case is where a composer writes a score, in Western notation using tools like [Finale](http://www.finalemusic.com/finale/default.aspx) or [Sibelius](http://www.sibelius.com/products/sibelius/7/index.html) or some such, which includes parts for Chinese or South Asian instruments. Currently, the performers of those instruments might rewrite their part by hand into the notation they are familiar with. This takes them hours. We'd like to enable the composer or their assistant to generate parts in the desired notation as a simple, fast export or conversion task.

Is anyone familiar with tools to do this?  I haven't been able to come across any in web searches or talking to local inter-cultural composers.

[MusicXML](http://www.recordare.com/musicxml) is an obvious pivot format for this kind of conversion. It gives me access to many different notation tools in one go. Great!  Also, I see that MusicXML 3.0 added support for [*jianpu* clef elements](http://www.recordare.com/musicxml/dtd/attributes-module). Great!

Are there any reference MusicXML format documents showing off well-done *jianpu* notation?
Are there any notation tools which are able to write or read MusicXML documents with *jianpu* notation?

(I am also asking this question on the [MusicXML mailing list](http://www.recordare.com/musicxml/mailing-list).)

Comment: Fascinating question, but I'm removing the "xml" tag because it's not a question about XML.

Comment: Thanks, Michael. It would be great if someone could add the tag "musicxml"; I don't have the privileges for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've answered this question in more detail on the MusicXML mailing list. The short answer is no, there's nothing yet in these areas. I look forward to your pioneering efforts, which should inform us about what we need to add to support these repertoires, most notably jianpu, in the future.

There used to be a commercial program that handled jianpu notation but it was discontinued long ago. The manufacturer of the program kindly gave me a jianpu tutorial which guided the addition of the jianpu clef in MusicXML 3.0.

Alas, I don't think I can add a musicxml tag to this question either...

Comment: +1. "no", from an expert, isn't the happiest answer, but it's informative.

Comment: 3 years on and I'm curious how far MusicXML has come, if at all, with jian pu? There's quite a few cloud based sheet music apps but none of them supports the numbered notation sadly.

Comment: We are still at MusicXML 3.0 so there have been no changes yet in the specification. I don't know any software yet supporting this either. MusicXML development just moved to the new Music Notation Community Group at the W3C, so if you have expertise in this area please consider joining: https://www.w3.org/community/music-notation/